# How does a virtual function affect static_cast?

Tags: c++, class, casting, static-cast

If I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
  public:
  void Call(){std::cout << "Base";}
};

class Derived: public Base
{
  public:
  void Call(){std::cout << "Derived";}
};

int main() {
  Base *base = new Base;
  static_cast<Derived*>(base)->Call();

  return 0;
}
```

The call will be in `Derived::Call()`

However, if I make the Call() function in Base class virtual

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
  public:
  virtual void Call(){std::cout << "Base";}
};

class Derived: public Base
{
  public:
  void Call(){std::cout << "Derived";}
};

int main() {
  Base *base = new Base;
  static_cast<Derived*>(base)->Call();

  return 0;
}
```

It calls `Base::Call()`.

How does making the function virtual in Base class affects the static_cast?

Comment: The result is undefined, since there is no `Derived` object.

Comment: because you really create `Base` object, the virtual table cell point to `Base::Call`. virtual functions not afect `static_cast` but `base` really point not to `Derived` object, because this your code incorrect. if you try call virtual function which exist in derived but not in base - you at all got here full UB

Comment: Any time you use `static_cast`, **you are responsible** to ensure that the cast is valid (that is, that the actual object is of the derived type).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour of

```
Base *base = new Base;
static_cast<Derived*>(base)->Call();
```

Is undefined.

*"The call will be in Derived::Call()"* is one possible behaviour. *"It calls Base::Call()"* is another possible behaviour. Either behaviour, or any other behaviour is possible when it is undefined. The behaviour can change or remain the same as a consequence of adding a virtual function, or for any other reason, or for no reason at all as long as behaviour is undefined.